# location.href to a link without http://

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, location-href

I have a webpage - http://www.example.com/ - where I have a button. On click of the button I need to go to a particular link (www.google.com). The button is like :

```
<input type="button"
       onclick="javascript:location.href='www.google.com'"
       value="Click" />
```

But this button opens a page "http://www.example.com/www.google.com" which is wrong URL.

I have tried `window.location`, `document.location`, `document.location.href`, `location.href` but all in vain.

The URL in my onclick can not be restricted to begin with 'http://'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not include a protocol (such as for example http), your browser will interpret `www.google.com` as a link to `http://www.example.com/www.google.com`, since you are currently on `http://www.example.com`. Add whatever protocol you want to the href-string, but if you are referring to somewhere else than on the site itself, you must have the protocol.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "current" protocol by prefixing your URLs with `//`

Comment: I don't need to use the current protocol. I need to open a new page in the same window (www.google.com)

Comment: Then again, prepend your links with `http://` or `//`, there's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

prefixing **http://**  before url may solve your issue.

```
if (!url.match(/^http?:\/\//i) || !url.match(/^https?:\/\//i)) {
        url = 'http://' + url;
    }
```

check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856848/5803974) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684929/5803974) for more information.