# Why can't I open a link without http or https using window.open() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can click *"Open 1"* button to open a full link in a new tab in Chrome.

When I click *"Open 2"* button, I can't open a the link without `http` or `https`, the browser URL address displays `http://localhost:53484/www.google.com`.

How can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function open1() {
            window.open('http://www.google.com')
        }

        function open2() {
            window.open('www.google.com')
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type=button value="Open 1" onclick="open1()">

    <input type=button value="Open 2" onclick="open2()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can fix it by using a complete URL.

Comment: I think it has answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684740/javascript-window-open-without-http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http or https are *needed*  to open an external link (i.e. to access any website in the world wide web) – it won't ever work without this, this is the official protocol. So if you have a link without it, every browser will automatically add it.

Comment: Thanks! But the browser add `http://localhost:53484` before `www.google.com`

Comment: @HelloCW the browser is assuming you're trying to open a relative path. Using `http*` will tell it that you are opening an absolute one.